# React-Native Al borrar caché de aplicación (Android), se eliminar las imágenes

Tags: android, imagen, react-native, static

Lo que me pasa es lo siguiente:

- Muestro una imagen

```
<Image 
     source = {require('../images/logo_sinfondo.png')}
     style = {{width : 200, height : 200}}
/>
```

- La imagen se muestra perfectamente en la aplicación. Si voy al gestor de aplicaciones de Android y elimino todos los datos (incluida la caché), la imagen se borra, ya que al volver a entrar en la aplicación, no la muestra.
- He probado a cargarla desde URL, desde código Base64, con FastImage... y nada, sigue pasando lo mismo.
  No consigo encontrar una solución a este problema, ya que son imágenes estáticas (logos) que no van a cambiar (a no ser que las cambiemos directamente en el proyecto).
- Actualmente las tengo en la carpeta aplicación/src/images

Comment: Estas usando el comando npx react-native run-android? con npx? para crear proyectos,etc. usa npx para tener la ultima version de todo. He eliminado el almacenamiento cache y datos y aun sigue saliendo mi imagen logo de mi app para correrlo hago npx react-native run-android

Comment: Uso directamente react-native run-android y para generar el apk, gradlew assembleDebug/Release

Comment: Gracias por el aviso. He tenido que actualizar todas las dependencias y paquetes para que se me solucionara.